# Action when user click on the delete button on the keyboard in SwiftUI

Tags: keyboard, action, swiftui

I try to run a function when the user click on the delete button on the keyboard when he try to modify a Textfield.

How can I do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, however it requires subclassing `UITextField` and creating your own `UIViewRepresentable`

This answer is based on the fantastic work done by Costantino Pistagna in his [medium article](https://medium.com/@valv0/textfield-and-uiviewrepresentable-46a8d3ec48e2) but we need to do a little more work.

Firstly we need to create our subclass of `UITextField`, this should also conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

```swift
class WrappableTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var textFieldChangedHandler: ((String)->Void)?
    var onCommitHandler: (()->Void)?
    var deleteHandler: (() -> Void)?

    override func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()
        deleteHandler?()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let nextField = textField.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return false
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if let currentValue = textField.text as NSString? {
            let proposedValue = currentValue.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            textFieldChangedHandler?(proposedValue as String)
        }
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        onCommitHandler?()
    }
}
```

Because we are creating our own implementation of a `TextField` we need three functions that we can use for callbacks.

1. `textFieldChangeHandler` this will be called when the text property updates and allows us to change the state value associated with our `Textfield`.
2. `onCommitHandler` this will be called when we have finished editing our `TextField`
3. `deleteHandler` this will be called when we perform he delete action.

The code above shows how these are used. The part that you are particularly interested in is the `override func deleteBackward()`, by overriding this we are able to hook into when the delete button is pressed and perform an action on it. Depending on your use case, you may want the `deleteHandler` to be called before you call the `super`.

Next we need to create our `UIViewRepresentable`.

```
struct MyTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let tmpView = WrappableTextField()

    //var exposed to SwiftUI object init
    var tag:Int = 0
    var placeholder:String?
    var changeHandler:((String)->Void)?
    var onCommitHandler:(()->Void)?
    var deleteHandler: (()->Void)?

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyTextField>) -> WrappableTextField {
        tmpView.tag = tag
        tmpView.delegate = tmpView
        tmpView.placeholder = placeholder
        tmpView.onCommitHandler = onCommitHandler
        tmpView.textFieldChangedHandler = changeHandler
        tmpView.deleteHandler = deleteHandler
        return tmpView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WrappableTextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyTextField>) {
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    }
}
```

This is where we create our SwiftUI version of our `WrappableTextField`. We create our `WrappableTextField` and its properties. In the `makeUIView` function we assign these properties. Finally in the `updateUIView` we set the content hugging properties, but you may choose not to do that, it really depends on your use case.

Finally we can create a small working example.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        MyTextField(tag: 0, placeholder: "Enter your name here", changeHandler: { text in
            // update the state's value of text
            self.text = text
        }, onCommitHandler: {
            // do something when the editing finishes
            print("Editing ended")
        }, deleteHandler: {
            // do something here when you press delete
            print("Delete pressed")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ! but is there a way to do that in a global way ? 
To run the action when the user clicks on the delete button without it being linked to the textfield element ?

Comment: like UIApplication.shared.endEditing() function ?

Comment: I don’t think so.